# Use image in for each but with different onclicks

Tags: javascript, for-loop, cookies

I'm making a table with a for each loop.
In every row i want to add a image but with different onclicks.
This is what i got now. All the "onclicks" are edited to the last for each round.

```
function cart(){
count = readCookie("count");
tableRow = "";
for (i = 1; i <= count; i++){
    item = "item" + i;
    Cookie = readCookie(item);
    if (!(Cookie == null)){
        row = new Array();
        row = Cookie.split("|");
        tableRow += "<tr>"
        + "<td>" + row[0] + "</td>" 
        + "<td>" + row[1] + "</td>" 
        + "<td>" + row[2] + "</td>" 
        + "<td>" + row[3] + "</td>" 
        + "<td>" + row[4] + "</td>" 
        + "<td>" + row[5] + "</td>" 
        + "<td>" + row[4] * row[5] + "</td>" + "<td>" 
        + "<a href=''><img src='img/delete.png' onclick='editCart(item);'></a>" 
        + "</td>" + "</tr>";
    }
}
document.write(tableRow);}
```

I know cookies are not the best way to do it but it's a school assignment.
Thats why even if you only like to give a hint i still would appreciate it.

Comment: Hint: 'i' is not the same thing as i (unquoted) ;)

Comment: Sorry, i edited my question. i'm using the var item and if you use a var you don't need to quote it. (i think) ;)

Comment: @Samichan it's still a problem. You dont quote vars, thats right, but you quoted it. That's your mistake.

Comment: What var do you mean? item = "item" + i; ? var item needs to be item1 or item2 so the second quoted item is not a var but a string.

Comment: No I'm talking about the line where you have the onclick attribute. The var item is quoted: `+ "editCart(item)"+` (simplified) So you have to unquote the item, to output the VALUE of the item, not the STRING _item_. Take a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"<a href=''><img src='img/delete.png' onclick='editCart(item);'></a>"
```

Every onclick call will be the same.

```
"<a href=''><img src='img/delete.png' onclick='editCart(\""+item+"\");'></a>"
```

This will generate the outputlink dynamically.

Comment: Couldn't check it yet. I'm now at my work, ill let you know when i tried it.

Comment: It shows (onclick="editCart(item3)") so it works now i need to find out why the onclick function doesn't work anymore. But i think i got that,  thanks for the help. I would vote you up but i don't have enough reputation points.

Comment: @Samichan It should output something like _onclick="editCart(3)"_ to the browser.

Comment: No it needs to be something like item3. As you see on the fifth line it says: item = "item" + i;
The cookies are named something like item3

Comment: @Samichan oh I see. But I don't get what you want to do with the var `row`

Comment: row = new Array(); was an unnecessary var that i took out of my code. I have know idee how it got back. (properly a screwup from me)

Comment: Strangely it doesn't. It shows the correct code in the web inspector on the browser but when i click the button it shows "reference error can't find variable item3"

Comment: Is your example online? I could take a look

Comment: No i only have the site local, but i do have a zip file with the files.
Only problem the names are in dutch. I hope its not a big problem.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ox198pmfmm4tznh/Archive.zip?dl=0

Comment: When does the error happen? My winkelwagen is empty, btw.

Comment: If you add something to the cart from xxlcomputers.html and than try to delete it with the X button. The error only appears a second in the web inspector (Chrome don't saves local cookies. for example Safari does)

Comment: @Samichan I've edited my answer. It works now for me. The problem was that in the `onclick="editCart(item1)"` the var `item1` was not definded (obviously), so it needs some quotation marks. It will get passed as a string now. The `\\` is necessary, because the double quation mark would be just a syntax error.

Comment: It works like a charm! Thank you for your time and knowledge.